# How do I report players in Halo: The Master Chief Collection on PC?

Tags: pc, halo-reach, halo-the-master-chief-collection

I came across an abusive player in Halo: Reach (PC) that was calling people racist slurs. I've already muted them by opening the scoreboard <kbd>Tab</kbd> and selecting their name, but I couldn't find any way to report them.

How do I report abusive players in Halo: The Master Chief Collection on Steam?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**On Windows 10, you can report recent players through the [Xbox Console Companion app](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/console-companion-app).**<sup>1</sup>

> To report a player that behaved in an inappropriate way or has an
>   inappropriate name or Gamertag:
>
> 1. Navigate to the **Friends** menu. If the player is not a friend, select **Followers** or **Recent players** from the drop-down menu to bring up the
>      relevant list. You can also search for the player by typing their
>      Gamertag into the search bar.
> 2. Select the Gamertag you wish to report.
> 3. Select **More**, and then select **Report**.
> 4. Select a reason for the report.
> 5. Provide any additional information in the text box, and then select **Report to Xbox**.
>
> Source: *[Xbox Enforcement - Submit a report on the Xbox app](https://enforcement.xbox.com/en-US/Home/HowTo#sub-topic3-0)*

[image: Reporting a player in the Console Companion app]

<sup><sup>1</sup>Previously known as the Xbox app before being [rebranded in June 2019](https://www.engadget.com/2019/06/05/the-xbox-app-for-windows-10-is-now-a-console-companion/).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [there is not an in-game report function](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/f3681fbc78fa43878c4aec9a63a46224/topics/how-to-report-toxic-players/415d6333-ae00-4b6e-9f35-cbba0d6bbcfc/posts). I find it surprising that a game of this magnitude lacks such a crucial feature.

Your best option, in this case, is to view their Xbox Live/Microsoft profile and report them there.

Comment: It seems you can't report from an Xbox Live profile. Clicking "Report" redirects me to a guide on [how to submit reports on Xbox One](https://enforcement.xbox.com/en-US/Home/HowTo#sub-topic2-0).

Comment: Sorry, I don't own the game - I can't advise further. While looking online I did see a few posts on the 343 website where players called out cheaters via the forum. Overall it seems 343 doesn't provide a lot of options to report players

Comment: @PausePause For what it's worth, it doesn't fully have to do with 343 Industries. It really wasn't that intuitive to report a player back on the Xbox360 when Bungie was over the Halo series.